# Analyzing building proximity to restaurants using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, proximity

I am trying to make a script that will go through buildings in a shapefile row-by-row and do a count of points within .25, .5,...1 mile of it. The other points are restaurants.

```
import arcpy  
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\zafard\Desktop\Building.gpd"  

#need to do 4 iterations for the distance radii
buffDist = [0.25,0.5,0.75,1]                              
for Dist in buffDist:
    print ("FOR A %s MILE RADIUS: " % (Dist))
    inTable = "C:\Users\zafard\Desktop\Building\XYBuild.shp"

    #set up cursor in table
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inTable)
    row = rows.next()

    #set up loop to analyze every row of the table
    While row:
        print row.OBJECTID  

        #use select by distance tool    
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("FRest","WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", row, Dist, "NEW_SELECTION")

        #count the hopefully selected points for the layer.
        count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("FRest"))

        print count
        row = rows.next()
```

I am now getting an error with running the tool in the while loop:

> Object: Error in executing tool

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your two feature layers are FRest and XYBuild, right? At first glance, I think the problem might be the paths to your feature layers. Is Building a geodatabase? If so the extension seems wrong (shouldn't be .gdb?). And is XYbuild is in the Building geodatabase? If that is the case then is not a shapefile and your should assign only "XYbuild" to your inTable variable.

Comment: Not certain but I think the shapefiles are being stored in a folder called C:\Users\zafard\Desktop\Building.gpd rather than the latter being a misnamed file geodatabase

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have the syntax issues sorted out, there might be a better approach performance-wise. You can use [PointDistance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Point_Distance/00080000001r000000/) to get an output table of all of the restaurant points within the search radius of each building. Next, use [SummaryStatistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/) to get the count for each building. The statistics_field parameter would be [['near_fid', 'count']] and the case field would be input_fid.

Comment: I got rid of the period (THANKS!) and still have an error on the print count.

Comment: count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("FRest"))

Comment: great find! yeah it runs now, but only does one iteration of the while loop before saying 
"Runtime error <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: Object: Error in executing tool"

Comment: sorry, it just does the OID and cannot run the the tools at all. My first day at arcpy scripting. Sorry..................

Comment: I think my main problem is that when I say the row it might not use the coordinates in that row??

Comment: No problem, everyone's new at some point. Where is "FRest" coming from and is it a feature layer? SelectLayerByLocation_management requires a layer for input. I believe you'll need to use MakeFeatureLayer_management since the select features parameter(where you're using row) is a layer as well.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. but how do I make a layer out of a cursor row?

Comment: I looked things over and updated the original answer with some new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\zafard\Desktop\Building.gpd"
```

needs to be changed to one of the following:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\zafard\Desktop\Building.gpd"   
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\zafard\\Desktop\\Building.gpd"   
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/zafard/Desktop/Building.gpd"
```

Similarly for:

```
inTable = "C:\Users\zafard\Desktop\Building\XYBuild.shp"
```

Also to use the geometry stored for each row this line:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("FRest","WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", row, Dist, "NEW_SELECTION")
```

should be:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("FRest","WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", row.Shape, Dist, "NEW_SELECTION")
```